# Make text visible from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a droppable area where user can drop item. And I have a field which counts difference between required and dropped items. Here is [example](https://jsfiddle.net/montel388/d1ddsj8m/7/)

And line where I display difference after dropping item:

```
$(this).closest("div.proc")
       .find('.dif')
       .text('Difference: ' + ( $(this).closest("div.proc").find('.numbr').text() - n) );
```

The problem is how can I display difference from the beginning. So user can see it even without dropping any item. Thank you

Comment: You can put this in document onLoad or some event ? 
Or you can just put the count when the document loads (as in html)

Answer (score 0):

Insert this in your code:

```
$(".dif").each(function(){
   var $e = $(this);
   $e.text('Difference: ' + $e.closest("div.proc").find('.numbr').text());
});
```

in the outermost scope (like just after `var itm = [];`).

Comment: i dont need duplication of required number, because if user saves dropped items and then want to edit them systm will show required number instead of difference

Answer (score 0):

Put your logic in `$(document).ready()` and display `text` for each `div` as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.projLeader label').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.dropped').text("Items Dropped :0")
        $(this).find('.dif').text("Difference : "+$(this).find('.numbr').text())
    })
})
```

**## UPDATED DEMO**

Comment: it works, but the problem is that if lets say user save dropped items and then want to edit it system will display required number again, but not the actual difference. Therefore I need to display exactly the difference and not duplicate required number

Comment: **lets say user save dropped items and then want to edit it**, Do you have some DB functionality over here??

Comment: yes I do. my system saves all dropped items. Then when i want edit it, system should display difference from the beginning. But now it appears only after I dropped any item to the field. So for example: required Number:10, I dropped 4 items then saved it. Then I want to edit it, system doesnt show any difference until i drop item, only then it will show 5.(as there was 4 and i drop 1 more)

Comment: So, where you are storing this data? I mean the one fetched from the server? Are you appending it as an any `data-*` attribute to elements or how will you get it?